# Storage collision in vyper hashmap?

Tags: storage, mapping, vyper

Can you get a storage collision in vyper?

The [HashMap](https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=mapping#mappings) value is stored at the `keccack256` of the key.

So wouldn't this mean storage collisions are possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ***storage collisions*** are possible in Vyper, it's not about Vyper or Solidity, it's about Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM).

Both languages use the same mechanism, `keccak256` to calculate storage locations for their mappings.

Solidity computes the location for a mapping's value as:

```
keccak256(key, slotPosition);
```

while Vyper does it as:

```
keccak256(slotPosition, key)
```

Here, `key` is the **HashMap** key, and `slotPosition` is the storage slot for the HashMap.

Since Keccak-256 is a strong hash function, it's very unlikely for two different keys to have the same storage place.

This means storage collisions are possible but very rare.